# Storing questions asked from table using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, persistence

My goal is to ask a series of questions.  Kind of like flashcards.  I have the questions in a table, and I can load them into a hash and ask them at random.  The problem is that I want to be able to ask a particular question once per review session.  The problem I have is that as soon as the page loads I lose the history and the hash resets to all the questions.  How do you solve this using (just) Rails?  I know the answer is probably "use JavaScript" but was wondering if it was possible using pure Rails.
One solution I thought of was creating a temp table and pulling all the questions there, and then deleting the question as soon as it's asked.  Is that the best solution?

Answer (score 2):

Just use rails session to store information about your survey between requests: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/.